# how to completely reformat a usb using fdisk?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, fdisk

I have a usb drive which I would like to put a linux distribution on but it already has some files on it on /dev/sdc1.  Using fdisk, I deleted the first partition and wrote the changes.  When I printed the table, the first partition was gone.

Then I created a new partition (/dev/sdc1).

However when I wrote these changes to the usb, the old files were still there.  I followed these instructions after deleting the first partition
http://www.zorge.net/?p=22

Are there any commands in fdisk (I'm trying to get comfortable in fdisk, so no gparted for me) to completely wipe out all the information on a drive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fdisk` manages partitions, but does not format or write data to the disk.

To format the disk, use `mkfs`

```
# FAT
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdxy # /dev/sdxy is your usb

# Or for ext4
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdxy
```

However, formatting does not overwrite your data, it just removes the pointers to where it is. To overwrite your data you actually need to write over it, use `dd` or a utility such as `scrub`

```
scrub /dev/sdxy
```

See also [man scrub](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scrub)